# Evolution mail says I have 700 mails but my inbox is empty

Tags: evolution

My inbox is empty when I try to link gmail to evolution mail client,  anyone can help?

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution,  I turned on "lesser secure" on my gmail account and everything works.

Here is the link:
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Simply click *activate*